# No projective modules in category.

Tags: homological-algebra

I have an exercise that reads:

Let $C$ be a the category of all finite $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, prove that there are no projective modules in $C$.

So, in order for $P$ to not be projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module I must prove that for every surjection $g: P \to M$ and every $f: N \to M$ it can't  exist a homomorphism $h: P \to N$ such that $f \circ h = g$. My question is, as we are working in $C$ are both the modules $N$ and $M$ also assumed to be finite $\mathbb{Z}$-modules? Also, is a proof my contradiction a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, projective modules $P$ are *free* $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. However, since $P$ is finite of order $n$, we have $nP=0$, so that $P$ is not free - see [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319901/free-mathbbz-modules).

Comment: Thank you. I think i mixed it up a little, finite here means finite number of elements and not finitely generated?

Comment: Yes,  *finite* $\mathbb{Z}$-module, i.e., having finitely many elements.

Comment: Can u provide any proof or idea for a proof for the fact that  $P$ is free because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID?

Comment: For this see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618539/prove-that-m-is-a-free-module-if-and-only-if-m-is-a-projective-module-over), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671545/projective-module-over-a-pid-is-free).

Comment: Not that it changes the answer in this specific case, but some extra care is needed. The stated result is when working in the category of all the modules. Restricting to a subcategory can in some cases introduce new projectives.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, that was what I was thinking, I am a little confused: when considering the homomorphisms in my question, are we assuming that $M, N$ are also finite $\mathbb{Z}$-modules or can they be any $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

Comment: @Sodan They must be finite. We never wish to consider anything outside the category.